# Schematics for basic z80180 system

Tags: schematics

I'm looking to build a very basic computer around the Z8180 MCU, I'm looking for a schematics to get a start.

I got a bit experience with fundamental electronics, but I never dabbled with any type of CPU/MCU before.

Any tips to get started is very appreciated.

I might add that the choice of processor is purely sentimental and there fore very definitive , Z80 it has to be, even if alternative is both better and simpler :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: +1 for stating sentimentality as the definitive choice for the processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.g-photo.net/projects/hwproj3/gcb_manual_a.pdf) is something that should get you started.